# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Unmanaged<__ObjC.NSString>' to 'Swift.AnyHashable' (0x11075f040)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Below is my code, error is shown in withOptions : block

```
 KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack     : NSNumber(value: false),
  KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration   : NSNumber(value: 1.0),                         
   KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity      : NSNumber(value: 0.3)
```

I'm trying to implement THCalendarDatePicker Calendar in my project.

```
  @IBAction func dateButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    datePicker.date = curDate as Date!
    datePicker.setDateHasItemsCallback({(date: Date!) -> Bool in
        let tmp = (arc4random() % 30) + 1
        return tmp % 5 == 0
    })
    presentSemiViewController(datePicker, withOptions: [
        KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack     : NSNumber(value: false),
        KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration   : NSNumber(value: 1.0),
        KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity      : NSNumber(value: 0.3)
        ])
}
```

Comment: You should try another library, the `KNSemiModalViewController` has not been updated for 4 years.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this error , Below is my code :

```
@IBAction func dateButtonTouched(sender: AnyObject) {
    datePicker.date = curDate as Date!
    datePicker.setDateHasItemsCallback({(date: Date!) -> Bool in
        let tmp = (arc4random() % 30) + 1
        return tmp % 5 == 0
    })
    presentSemiViewController(datePicker, withOptions: [
        convertCfTypeToString(cfValue: KNSemiModalOptionKeys.shadowOpacity) as String! : 0.3 as Float,
        convertCfTypeToString(cfValue: KNSemiModalOptionKeys.animationDuration) as String! : 1.0 as Float,
        convertCfTypeToString(cfValue: KNSemiModalOptionKeys.pushParentBack) as String! : false as Bool
        ])
}

/* https://vandadnp.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/swift-convert-unmanaged-to-string/ */
func convertCfTypeToString(cfValue: Unmanaged<NSString>!) -> String?{
    /* Coded by Vandad Nahavandipoor */
    let value = Unmanaged<CFString>.fromOpaque(
        cfValue.toOpaque()).takeUnretainedValue() as CFString
    if CFGetTypeID(value) == CFStringGetTypeID(){
        return value as String
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```